# How to upload a file to FTP via curl but from stdin?

Tags: curl

Basically, I'm trying to do this:

`some_other_program | curl ftp://username:password@192.168.1.10/file.txt`

As a test case to see if I can get it working, I'm trying it with `cat` like so:

`cat test.txt | curl -d @- ftp://admin:PASS@192.168.1.10/file.txt`

Notice, I tried the `-d @-` thing, but it doesn't work.  How do I do this?

[This question is similar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77588/passing-binary-data-to-curl-without-using-a-file), but that one is about HTTP, my question is about FTP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a file to an FTP server that doesn't properly terminate the connection on success?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341233/how-to-send-a-file-to-an-ftp-server-that-doesnt-properly-terminate-the-connecti)

Comment: Use `-T -` for ftp instead of `-d @-` which is just for http.

Comment: That works thanks!  Make it the answer and I'll mark it (why don't people just do that?)

Answer (score 9):

`curl`'s `-T` accepts `-` to read from stdin.

The command reads like:

```
cat test.txt | curl -T - ftp://admin:PASS@192.168.1.10/file.txt
```

Here's an example used to upload a file to Vimeo directly:

```
gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/video.mp4 - | curl -T - ftp://user:PASS@ftp-3.cloud.vimeo.com/video.mp4
```